# Data.frame after transpose and data.frame still gives variables as non-numeric

Tags: dataframe, header, numeric, transpose, vegan

I find myself struggling with data import for further nMDS and Bioenv analysis with "vegan" and "ggplot2". I have a data frame  "Taxa" that looks like this (the values are there to mean it is "numeric".   —

> head(Taxa)
>
> ```
>     X1      Station1   Stations1_2     Stations1_3  ...
>
>   Species1    123           456              789
>
>   Species2    123           456              789
>
>    Species3    123           456              789
> ```
>
> ...

After I transpose my data to have the stations (observations) as rows

> Taxa <- t(Taxa)

```
       X_1        Species1     Species2     Species3  ...
     Station1      123           456              789
     Species1_2    123           456              789
     Species1_3    123           456              789
```

...

Now if I check how the data has been transposed I see that it has been converted into a "matrix"

> class(Taxa)
>   [1] "matrix"

Now I can change again the matrix into a data frame

> Taxa.df <- data.frame(Taxa)

And what I get then is the following:

> head(Taxa.df)

```
                       X1          X2             X3 
          X_1        Species1     Species2     Species3  ...
          Station1      123           456              789
          Species1_2    123           456              789
          Species1_3    123           456              789
          ...
```

Now what I would need is to get the first row to become the columns header so that I can restore the initial structure

colnames(Taxa.df)=Taxa.df[1,]

When I do this this happens to the data frame

```
                         23          10             16    ....    
           X_1        Species1     Species2     Species3  ...
           Station1      123           456              789
           Species1_2    123           456              789
           Species1_3    123           456              789
           ...
```

I don't manage to get to have the first row as header.

If I can't do this I can't run the transformation I need and all the stats analysis I still need to run. I spent the whole day simply trying to import the data from xlsx on Rstudio for Mac and solve this issue. I hope you guys can help. I did already look around a lot and mostly thought to have found these two links as useful answers, but nothing solved my exact problem.

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Transposing-Data-Frame-does-not-return-numeric-entries-td852889.html

[Why does the transpose function change numeric to character in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216197/why-does-the-transpose-function-change-numeric-to-character-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

The first variable in your data frame was `X1` with values `Species1` etc. You should have read your data so that the first variable is numeric (`Species1`) which you can achieve with argument `row.names=1` in the `read.*` command. Alternatively, you can only  transpose the numeric data and then label the rows and columns with the original data. The following may work

```
mat <- t(Taxa[,-1]) # remove col 1
colnames(mat) <- rownames(Taxa)
mat <- as.data.frame(mat)
```

However, I think you have not posted the actual output of your **R** commands, but written by hand the things you *think* are essential to the structure. So it may be that your data are different than you display, and you may also have non-numeric rows. Just check `sum(Taxa)` which is number if your data are numeric, and `sum(Taxa[,-1])` which is a number if removing the first column is sufficient, and `summary(Taxa)` which gives `Mean` and `Median` for columns which are all numeric (including first row).

Comment: Thank you Jari, very useful!